# SPF Fail while sending mail using office 365 for sending email

Tags: email, office365, spf

I have configured office 365 for sending email from my application. Email is sent successfully, but when I check in received email header it shows me like Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of mydomain.com does not designate 192.185.45.210 as permitted sender). I have change SPF in my domain like

```
v=spf1 a mx include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

but still, I got the same error message in the email. I have also try below code too.

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:mydomain2.com -all
```

and there is also message like

```
Received: from gateway21.websitewelcome.com
```

why websitewelcome.com is there though I am not using this type of setting in my whole application. I have integrated office365 email account in laravel application.

Answer (score 1):

The IP it's complaining about does belong to websitewelcome.com, presumably because your site is hosted there, so I suggest you add their SPF too:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:websitewelcome.com -all
```

It's always worth checking your SPF on [Scott Kitterman's site](https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?).

Comment: no my site is not hosted on websitewelcome.com it is hosted on bluehost

Comment: That SPF failure is coming from websitewelcome (look up the reverse DNS for `192.185.45.210`), so something is wrong with your config if you think that's the case.

Comment: i have develop application in laravel and in laravel's configuration i have mention office 365's mail account for sending emails. i have check nowhere in my code websitewelcome.com is mention.

Comment: It's got to be there somewhere or it would not be happening - it may be outside your app config, like in DNS.

Comment: You mean to say that someone has change in my dns record or it is hacked

Comment: No, as in you missed something. Trace all the IP addresses, check your DNS entries. Don't assume; check.

Comment: there is nothing in domain entries related to welcomewebsite.com

Comment: I have check thries in my domain entries as well as complete code. my application is hosted on bluehost server.

Comment: It’s there somewhere. I can’t look for you.